# Which is best way for creating session for login user in Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jwt

This time I am working **Ionic Framework** app which is new to me and Now I am stuck with one thing.

For authentication of user login which is best way to do.

1) By writing `Session.create()` like thing

2) By using JSON Web Token (JWT)

Please provide me some information that weather is it best to use **JWT** for
 authentication purpose for **Ionic Framework** App or is there any other alternative for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use JSON web token's, they are easy to use and effective. Now, how you authenticate before giving out web tokens is up to you. At the company I work for our ionic app uses the nonce nonce variable system to securely authenticate users without having to pass their password over the connection. What happens is they do a post with their user name and this returns a random integer or a nonce. The server stores the nonce and then we apply a numerical operation on the nonce (client and server side) then we has together the username, password, nonce, and nonce variable and see if they match. If they do we pass them a web token. If you want more backing for the web token look here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sessions-or-cookies-angularjs-phonegap/613/7